# How to use d3.domain/range to have a custom domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend

I'm currently using the whole idea of

```
var myQuantizeFunction = d3.scale.quantize()
                                 .domain(minMaxFromData) // the minmax using d3.extent
                                 .range(['bla-1', 'bla-2', 'bla-3', 'bla-4', 'bla-5']);
```

So this works fine when you want to generate a legend across your min-max. The issue is, I have some data which comes back as 0.

Here is an example legend for context :

[image: legend image]

As you can see, it's first or lowest value from the range is 0 - 4.7, what I want to really do is have 0 (ie none) as it's own legend item and have everything above ie 1 - 33 in this case as the other ranges.

I want to be able to specify that the first range is 0 and then the domain is split equally between values > 0.

Is there a d3 way of doing this? I'm sure someone else must have had this same problem before, I can't seem to find it but I may not be using the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I improved [the latest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782123/2739274) to use `d3.min()` and added code to the test the quantize function. Also I added a small function to colorize the output.

Everything done in the d3 datadriven way

```
data = [0,0,2,1,4,6,7,8,4,3,0,0];
range = ['bla-1', 'bla-2', 'bla-3', 'bla-4', 'bla-5'];

//strip the first element
reducedRange = range.slice();
reducedRange.shift();

var myQuantizeFunction = 
    d3.scale.quantize()
      .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
      .range(reducedRange);

var filterQuantize = function(d){
  if(d==0){
    return range[0];
  }else{
    return myQuantizeFunction(d);
  }
}

var colorize = d3.scale.category10();
// To test this we will put all the data in paragraphs
d3.select('body').selectAll('p').data(data)  .enter()
  .append('p')
  .text(function(d){return d+':'+filterQuantize(d);})
  .style('color',function(d){return colorize(d)});
```

[View this code runing](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwvQXq)

Hope this helps, good luck!

**Update:** I stripped zero out of the scale to treat it as a special case as you pointed in the comment.

Comment: this doesn't help because not only does it return bla-1 for '0' values as expected it also returns bla-1 for '1'. I wanted bla-1 to be for '0' values only and the rest of the bla's to be returned for anything other. I've managed to do this but not in a d3 way, a very manually, array pushing not so neat javascript way. I think I wasn't able to display my question simply enough.

Comment: Now I get it, i don't figure out why you want to strip 0 out of the scale, but you can do it by wraping it around your own function. I have updated the code

Comment: This is something very similar to what I've done. This actually answers the question directly, so I shall try and tick this as the answer. However OAuth is right in talking about the d3.min also returning 0. My comment needs to be your domain d3.extent(data, function (d) { if (d.value > 0) { return d.value; }}); (Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> #### quantize.domain([numbers])
>
> If numbers is specified, sets the scale's input domain to the
> specified two-element array of numbers. If the array contains more
> than two numbers, only the first and last number are used. If the
> elements in the given array are not numbers, they will be coerced to
> numbers; this coercion happens similarly when the scale is called.
> Thus, a quantize scale can be used to encode any type that can be
> converted to numbers. If numbers is not specified, returns the scale's
> current input domain.

As the name suggests d3 is 'data driven' so ignoring parts of your data set is not part of its ethos.

You need to write your own function to generate the `[numbers]` array.

Try:

```
data = [0,0,2,1,4,6,7,8,4,3,0,0];

min = undefined;
data.forEach(function (v) {
    if (v > 0) {
        if (typeof(min) === 'undefined') {
            min = v;
        } else if (v < min) {
            min = v;
        }
    }
})

var myQuantizeFunction = d3.scale.quantize()
                                 .domain([min, d3.max(data)])
                                 .range(['bla-1', 'bla-2', 'bla-3', 'bla-4', 'bla-5']);
```

Comment: My function basically needs to set the min/max to everything MORE THAN 0. So the min needs to be MORE than 0 or whatever the lowest non 0 value in my data is. This looks like something I can do in the d3.extent method.var minMaxFromData = d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.value; }); Probably modify this to only return when the value is NOT 0.

Comment: There is a slightly more elegant solution                      var minMaxFromData = d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                         if (d.value > 0) {
                         return d.value;
                     }});

Comment: This will  take into account the numbers which are more than 0 when generating the min/max, However thanks for your help :) I'm getting there. I'll mark your answer as correct still as it does somewhat answer the question.

Comment: You can also use d3.min to get the data minimum

Comment: @DavidLemon But this would return 0, in the example `min` is the smallest value greater than 0.